# Axios - update headers on exported axios.create instance

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6, vuejs2, axios

I have one `api.js` which exports by default an `axios.create()` instance:

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
    Authorization: `Bearer ${Cookies.get('Token')}`,
    Organization: Cookies.get('Organization'),
    Company: Cookies.get('Company')
  }
})

export default api
```

Then I import this in multiple files like this:

```
//api/users.js
import api from './api.js'

const methods = {
  postUser (params) {
    return api.post('/users', params)
  },
  getUser (id) {
    return api.get('/users/' + id)
  }
}

export default methods
```

However there will be some functions that should update the Cookies `Organization` and `Company` and I was wondering if is possible to update the default `api` instance and automatically update it in all imports that use it. I know a simple page refresh would work but I'm building a SPA and I would like to prevent screen to be manually refreshed.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can add the headers dynamically, that way the cookies will be read on every request.

```
import axios from 'axios'
import Cookies from 'js-cookie'

const api = axios.create({
  baseURL: process.env.VUE_APP_API_URL,
  timeout: 10000,
  // Static headers
  headers: {
    'Content-Type': 'application/json',
  },
  transformRequest: [function (data, headers) {
    // You may modify the headers object here
    headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${Cookies.get('Token')}`
    headers['Organization'] = Cookies.get('Organization')
    headers['Company'] = Cookies.get('Company')

    // Do not change data
    return data;
  }],
})

export default api
```

Comment: That's what I'm looking for! Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

I would suggest to read about interceptor for axios. (https://github.com/axios/axios#interceptors)

A very basic example would be the following.
Lets assume your webservice would return a response http status 401 header.
You'd intercept the response with the following:

```
// Add a response interceptor
axios.interceptors.response.use(function (response) {
    // happy case its 2XX
    return response;
  }, async (error) => {
    if (error.response.status === 401) {
        // do some logic to retrieve a new JWT or Cookie.get()
        const jwt = Cookies.get('Token');
        const config = error.config;
        config.headers['Authorization'] = `Bearer ${jwt}`;
    }
    
    return await axios.request(config);
});
```

The next request will then have an authorization header attached to the request header.

Comment: Hello, I'm already using the interceptors for other things, that's really useful. I solved my problem with @Michael2 answer, using `transformRequest`. Thanks for the help!